# Is there a function than transitions smoothly between two values, over an interval and remains constant elsewhere?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Specifically, does it exists an infinitely differentiable function $f:R \to R$ that meets the following conditions?.

- $f(x)=0$ if $x \le 0$.
- $f(x)=1$ if $x \ge 1$.

Physical interpretation: Is there a smooth way to move an object constrained to move along a line so that it begins and ends at rest (speaking of "beginning" and "end" implies a finite amount of time)?.

I'm aware than without the boundary conditions, the exponential function would be a valid answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the function $h(x)=\frac{g(x)}{g(1-x)+g(x)}$, where $g(x)=e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$. This $h$ is smooth because it is the quotient of two smooth functions, with non-vanishing denominator.

Answer (score 3):

a standard example for this kind of smoothing over a discontinuity is the real function $f(x)$ which is zero if $|x| \ge 1$ and for $|x| \lt 1$ is defined as:
$$
f(x) = e^{-(1-x^2)^{-1}}
$$
this function can be used in constructions to deal flexibly with other similar situations. you will find your way into the literature on the subject if you search for *bump functions* or *non-analytic smooth functions*

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $\,\varphi(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}\enspace x\le 0\enspace\text{or}\enspace x\ge 1,\\\mathrm e^{\tfrac1{x(x-1)}}&\text{if}\enspace 0<x<1.\end{cases}$

It is easy to check $\varphi$ is a $\,\mathcal C^{\infty}$ function from $\mathbf R\,$ to $\,[0,1]$.

Now set $k=\displaystyle\int_0^1\varphi(t)\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu t$ and:

$$f(x)=\frac 1k\int_0^x\varphi(t)\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu t$$
Since $\varphi$  is  $\,\mathcal C^{\infty}$, so is $f$, and $f(x)=0\,$ if $x\le 0$, $f(x)=1\,$ if $x\ge 1$, since $\varphi$ has support in $[0,1]$.